# Duvida envolvendo múltiplas condições em um IF usando Whiptail(TUI) em Shell Script

Tags: if, shell-script

Pessoal estou fazendo um arquivo simples de configuração em Shell script com uma TUI(Text User Interface) usando Whiptail, preciso restringir a entrada do usuário para que o programa aceite como entrada apenas um intervalo de números inteiros, consegui fazer funcionar de forma braçal, mas inviável para definir grandes intervalos. segue um trecho...

***Dessa forma funciona perfeitamente, apenas é uma maneira "burra" de se fazer e inviável para definir grandes intervalos***
***status2 é o status de saída é (0 para confirma e 1 para cancelar)
intervalo é o valor inserido pelo usuário***

---

```
intervalo=$(whiptail --title "Entre com o valor em sugundos do intevalo de verificação do ruído ambiente" --inputbox "Entre com um inteiro de 0 a 9 (recomendado:1)" --fb 10 80 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
status2=$? #echo "O status2 foi $status2 e intervalo= $intervalo" #sleep 4
if (( $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 1 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 2 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 3 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 4 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 5 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 6 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 7 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 8 || $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo == 9 )); then
        echo "Intervalo = $intervalo"
else
        echo "Configuração cancelada."
        exit 0
fi
```

---

Qual a maneira correta mais simples de definir as múltiplas condições deste laço `if`?? 
Algo como: `if ((  $status2 == 0  &&  $intervalo > 0 && $intervalo < 10); then`...

Assim não funciona e não restringe números não decimais.

Answer (score 0):

O teu código corrigido seria esse:

```
intervalo=$(whiptail --title "Entre com o valor em sugundos do intevalo de verificação do ruído ambiente" --inputbox "Entre com um inteiro de 0 a 9 (recomendado:1)" --fb 10 80 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
status2=$?
if [ $intervalo -ge 0 -a $intervalo -le 9 ]; then
    echo "Intervalo = $intervalo"
else
    echo "Configuração cancelada."
    exit 0
fi
```

E de fato a maneira mais simples seria fazendo um if com um range que é o **>= 0 and <= 9** que dentro do if [  ]; seria como:

> -le 0 -a -ge 9

e segundo também que você estava fazendo o teste no **$status2** e não na captura do dado que é a variável **$intervalo**